# The usage of "little" versus "a little"

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

I was taught that **"little"** is the negative form of **"a little"** [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTK3M19G06g&t=517s) [[2]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/little-a-little-few-a-few) [[3]](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/290/little-vs-a-little). So why don't we use "little" in these sentences? :

> I'm **a little confused.**

> I'm **a little worried** that the Biden team seems to want to do these
> things with full pay-fors.

> "I'm **a little concerned** that the intentions aren't genuine if I'm
> going to be completely honest."

For me, either form has a negative feeling, but I also know that the correct form is **"a little"** in these sentences. But why?

Comment: I don't understand why the negative point, ahaha. But ok.

Comment: “The negative form of” sounds like you mean they are antonyms, which they aren’t. After looking at your three references, the third (LanGeek) might imply this, but the others certainly don’t. Instead, when they use “negative”, they mean “having negative (bad) connotations”. I think this is also what you mean in your question, but answers so far seem to take the “antonym” interpretation and then argue against it. (Incidentally, I would say instead that “little” emphasises the *lack*, the smallness, while “a little” emphasises the *presence*. Positive or negative depends on context.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's accurate to say that "little" is the negative, the opposite, of "a little". It's more like a milder form.

"I felt little confusion." I felt some confusion, but not much. This wording implies, not enough to be a real problem.

"I felt a little confusion." I felt some confusion. Probably a middling amount. If I was very confused, I'd say, "I felt a lot of confusion" or "I felt a great deal of confusion."

If I wanted to say that everything was clear and I felt no confusion at all, I'd say, "I felt no confusion". (Or really more likely I'd state it positively, like "Everything was very clear".)

Note that sometimes people use mild wording to be polite. Like if you gave a presentation at a business meeting that was really bad and made no sense at all, someone might think, "That was very confusing. What in the world was he trying to say?" But to be polite they might say, "I'm a little confused. What were you trying to say?"

As Juhas notes, "little" is not often used as an adverb like this in American English. If you say it, it sounds rather formal. You might use it in a scholarly paper but few would use it in casual conversation.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Jay! I will take some notes. Have a nice day, friend.

Answer (score 2):

In my variety of English (Western US English), "I'm little confused/worried/concerned" sound incorrect.  We do not typically use *little* as an adverb in these situations.  There are some exceptions, such as "he is little known", but in general, we'd only use "a little" to modify verbs like *confused*, *worried*, or *concerned*.

However, this may not be the case in all varieties of English.  Macmillan Dictionary says this is American English:

> as an **adverb**: *I go there very little. I’m little affected by the cold*

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/little_1

In contrast, your second link, the Cambridge Dictionary, does not suggest that *little* is ever used as an adverb:

> *A little*: adverb
>
> We use a *little* as an adverb of degree. It is more formal than a bit:
>
> *He smiled just **a little**.*
>
> *Her hands were shaking **a little**.*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/little-a-little-few-a-few

What this means is that, in your context, for speakers like me, there is not a choice between "little confused" and "a little confused"; only the latter is correct.

But if you altered the sentences, so that we were using *little* as an adjective, we'd end up with a situation that mostly conforms to what you've been taught:

*I felt a little confusion* -> I felt some amount (neutral) of confusion

*I felt little confusion* -> I did not feel much (negative) confusion

*He expressed a little worry* -> He expressed some amount (neutral) of worry

*He expressed little worry* -> He did not express much (negative) worry

Comment: That was quite an answer! The use of "little" is clearer now.
  Thank you, Juhasz!

Comment: I can't see anything in the Macmillan definition that doesn't also apply to British English.

Answer (score 2):

As an adverb, "a little" means "some small amount".

As an adverb, "little" means "an insignificant amount" or "a problematically small amount". Which of these it means is determined from the context.

One is not "the negative" or "the opposite" of the other. They are simply different.

> I care **a little**. (*= I care somewhat*)
> I care **little**. (*= I don't care any significant amount*)

> There's **a little** food in the fridge. (*= there's some food, but not a lot*)
> There's **little** food in the fridge. (*= there's a problematically small amount of food in the fridge*)

So your example sentences mean, "*I'm somewhat confused/worried/concerned*".

They are neutral, and do not imply that the degree of confusion/worry/concern is insignificant or problematic.

The same sentences with "little" would mean, "*I'm not confused/worried/concerned to any significant degree.*"

Comment: So the use of little in the sentences I mentioned is possible and correct, right?

Comment: There's some sense to saying that they're opposites. "little" emphasizes the lack (but not total lack) of something, while "a little" emphasizes the existence of something (but only a small amount).

Comment: @Barmar "a little" doesn't emphasize anything. It's free of nuance. It simply means "some small amount" without suggesting anything about its significance. In contrast, "little" includes the nuance that the small amount either makes it insignificant or problematic. Calling them opposites will only lead to mistakes as learners will think "a little" has the opposite nuance, being that the small amount is necessarily significant or sufficient, which it is not.

Comment: @Portugueseporto Kind of. Using just "little" in your example sentences makes grammatically correct sentences, but not very natural ones. "*I'm **little** confused*" might have been natural English a few hundred years ago, but not today.

Answer (score 1):

**Little** is a negative idea. Little means **not** much.

There is **little** time. (**not** much time, not enough time)

**A little** is a positive idea. It means **some** or a small amount.

There is **a little** time. (**some** time, enough time)

We can say **a little confused, a little worried** and **a little concerned** (NOT little confused, little worried and little concerned)

('Only a little' has a negative meaning)